# Maven and Gitlab runner with nexus repository: 401 unauthorized

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci, nexus

I have a configuration with maven, gitlab-runner and nexus. The pipeline goes OK if the gitlab-runner is of type shell executor. But if I change the gitlab-runner to one of type docker executor. Then after download lots of dependencies from the nexus repository throws an exception due to 401 Unauthorized. The relevants parts of the configuration are:

settings.xml (with passwords omitted)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.openclover</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
      <username>theusername</username>
      <password></password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>nexus-releases</id>
      <username>theusername</username>
      <password></password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>central</id>
      <username>theusername</username>
      <password></password>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>central</name>
      <url>https://<my_domain>/repository/maven-group/</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>

</settings>
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<project>
...
  <!-- Repositories -->

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://<my_domain>/repository/maven-group/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <!-- //////////////// -->

  <!-- Distribution Management -->

  <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
      <url>https://<my_domain>/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus-releases</id>
      <url>https://<my-domain>/repository/maven-releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
...
</project>

  <!-- ///////////// -->
```

gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11


variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/settings.xml --batch-mode -X"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"

stages:
  - test

codetest:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean clover:setup test clover:aggregate clover:save-history clover:clover clover:log
```

And finally the exception:

```sh
 Downloading from central: https://<my_domain>/repository/maven-group/io/quarkus/quarkus-oidc/1.4.2.Final/quarkus-oidc-1.4.2.Final.jar
Downloading from central: https://<my_domain>/repository/maven-group/io/quarkus/quarkus-resteasy-jsonb/1.4.2.Final/quarkus-resteasy-jsonb-1.4.2.Final.jar
Downloading from central: https://<my_domain>/repository/maven-group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-validator/1.4.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-validator-1.4.2.Final.jar
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 7.461 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.duckdns.aqueipo.arqsw.unit.hateoas.HateoasManagerTest
[ERROR] testLinks  Time elapsed: 0.023 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.bootstrap.BootstrapException: Failed to create the application model for org.duckdns.aqueipo.arqsw:callejero::jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Caused by: io.quarkus.bootstrap.BootstrapException: Failed to create the application model for org.duckdns.aqueipo.arqsw:callejero::jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Caused by: io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.AppModelResolverException: Failed to resolve dependencies for org.duckdns.aqueipo.arqsw:callejero:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to collect dependencies at io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy:jar:1.4.2.Final
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy:jar:1.4.2.Final
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy:jar:1.4.2.Final
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy:pom:1.4.2.Final from/to central (https://<my_domain>/repository/maven-group/): Authentication failed for https://<my_domain>/repository/maven-group/io/quarkus/quarkus-resteasy/1.4.2.Final/quarkus-resteasy-1.4.2.Final.pom 401 Unauthorized
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy:pom:1.4.2.Final from/to central (https://<my_domain>/repository/maven-group/): Authentication failed for https://<my_domain>/repository/maven-group/io/quarkus/quarkus-resteasy/1.4.2.Final/quarkus-resteasy-1.4.2.Final.pom 401 Unauthorized
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Authentication failed for https://<my_domain>/repository/maven-group/io/quarkus/quarkus-resteasy/1.4.2.Final/quarkus-resteasy-1.4.2.Final.pom 401 Unauthorized
```

This job finalizes OK when the gitlab-runner is of type shell executor. Any idea??

Comment: If you have defined the consumption of your repository manager in your `settings.xml` you can remove it from your pom file. Furthermore does the `settings.xml` as defined in `$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/settings.xml` really exist?

Comment: The logs are showing that is using the expected settings.xml file ([DEBUG] Reading user settings from /builds/aqp696/argos/.m2/settings.xml). The configuration of the pom and settings are accordingly to this blog post from nexus sonatype: https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-1-maven-artifacts

Comment: The configuration in your pom file contains a definition of the repository which is useless if you have defined the `settings.xml` like that (apart from being really used).. Does this location `/builds/aqp696/argos/.m2/settings.xml` contains your mentioned settings.xml ?

Comment: The location /builds/aqp696/argos/.m2/settings.xml contains the previously mentioned settings.xml. This setup works OK when running gitlab-runner in mode shell executor, but fails with the previous exception when running in mode docker executor

Comment: That means the docker container does not see this location

Comment: That makes sense, but if I put for example `mvn compile` -> All the dependencies are downloaded OK with this same configuration and gitlab-runner with docker-executor. I have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: Maybe related to "https://github.com/takari/aether-connector-okhttp/issues/29". Can you try with "-Daether.connector.basic.threads=1"?

Answer (score 0):

I did the following which didn't help: tried deploy tokens, tried to hardcode deploy token in settings.xml and lots of other stuff, but what really helped is to upgrade maven. So I used the following image in gitlab CI:

maven:3.9.2-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine

That solved the problem.